# how to attach windows workflows to infopath

Tags: infopath

I am having infopath form . i have to attach the windows workflow to infopath. any body helps.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to attaching the workflow to a list, you must also tell it when to fire.  By default, SharePoint Designer workflows are set to be started manually by a user.  If you want it to fire when a form is added or changed, you must check those check boxes on the workflow properties page in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more information may be required.

If this InfoPath form lives in a SharePoint document library, then you attach the workflow to the document library, which is then triggered when an InfoPath form is saved in it.

Are you using a SharePoint Designer Workflow or Visual Studio workflow?